# Bootsrap full width on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On a desktop I would like to have 2 column.
On a mobile I would like to have only 1 column.

```
<div class="home">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12> 
...content---
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12>
...content...
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this code does not use the full width on a mobile phone. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand about Bootstrap I would say you do not need all of the col classes in your code. Just the col-xs-* classes.

```
<div class="home">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12> 
...content---
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12>
...content...
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The col-xs-12 will display across all browsers the same and they will be reformatted for smaller displays as well.

And I want to add that the columns would need to have rows inside them but I am assuming that is what the content is. And one other thing is to make sure that the columns used add up to 12. That can cause some errors as well

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is mobile first. It only requires column classes at the smallest breakpoint where you want the layout to change.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8> 
         ...content...
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4>
        ...content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code....may be solve your problem.

```
<div class="home">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12"> 
                <p>...content------</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <p>...content....</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have no close quotation marks after the last class.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12"> 
...content---
</div>
```

Comment: That does not solve it...I just forgot to add it into the sample code...I have searched already for a solution but it seems that this is an issue with bootstrap...

Comment: This is not a known issue as far as I know. What's with your content inside? If  it's not showing full width in mobile, how DOES it look? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: on my iphone it has 1 cm white space on the right and on the left hand side

Comment: just want to mention that the header incl navigation dropdown button and the footer are displayed correctly. It's just everything inbetween which does not look correct.

Comment: Then I would need to see your CSS and a screenshot. Also,  your classes should be in the reverse order, maybe that would do it. First xs, then md, then lg.